# Odds Ratio, Risk Ratio, and epitools package . When analyses should rely on crosstables only and depends on tidyverse environment

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, xtable

When working in *epidemiology*, ODDS Ratio and other measures of risk are always necessary. However, sometimes we do not model the data via glm, but solely on crosstabs. With that said, I wonder if someone could help to deal with *onequestions*:

**question 1.** Let's say I have a dataset with age_rank (factor) and headache_frequency (No headache Low-frequency Intermediate, and High-frequency) and I want to check the relationship of both variable and the odds of being assigned to **"no-headache"** / **low-frequency** (etc) groups as a function of the age_rank. Now, I'm creating several "dummies" to that:

```
ds <- ds %>% 
      mutate(no_headache = as.factor(if_else(headache_frequency == "No headache","yes","no")))
oddsratio(ds$age_group, ds$no_headache)
```

Then:

```
ds <- ds %>% 
  mutate(low_headache = as.factor(if_else(headache_frequency == "Low frequency","yes","no")))

oddsratio(ds$age_group, ds$low_headache)
```

I would like to make this solution faster by checking all groups. Firstly, I imagined that "filter" could be a nice option:

```
ds %>% 
  filter(headache_frequency == "No headache") %>% 
  oddsratio(headache_frequency, age_group)
```

But this error comes out to the results:

```
Error in oddsratio(., headache_frequency, age_group) : 
  object 'headache_frequency' not found
```

Then I imagined that I could group my data, but of course, this solution was impracticable:

```
ds %>% 
  group_by(headache_frequency) %>% 
  oddsratio(.,age_group)
```

Thank you.
As this question could be of interest of other people, please follow the code below to reproduce all commands:

```
dput(ds)

ds <- structure(list(headache_frequency = structure(c(4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                      4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                      3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No headache", 
                                                                                                                              "Low frequency", "Intermediate", "High frequency"), class = "factor"), 
                     age_group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
                     ), .Label = c("[10,12]", "(12,15]", "(15,Inf]"), class = "factor"), 
                     no_headache = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                               1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                               2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                               2L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), levels = c("yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", 
                                                                                                           "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"), low_headache = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -339L))
library(tidyverse)
library(epitools)
library(janitor)


#Create a specific variable
ds <- ds %>% 
  mutate(no_headache = as.factor(if_else(headache_frequency == "No headache","yes","no")))

# Odds Ratio 
oddsratio(ds$age_group, ds$no_headache)

ds <- ds %>% 
  mutate(low_headache = as.factor(if_else(headache_frequency == "Low frequency","yes","no")))

oddsratio(ds$age_group, ds$low_headache)


ds %>% 
  filter(headache_frequency == "No headache") %>% 
  oddsratio(headache_frequency, age_group)



ds %>% 
  group_by(headache_frequency) %>% 
  oddsratio(.,age_group)
```

Comment: Please just ask one question at a time when posting on Stack Overflow focusing on one specific problem. General questions asking for package recommendations are considered off topic. In general R packages try to be small and focused on doing one thing well. It's rare that you will find one package to "do everything."

Comment: You could easily calculate the odds of each outcome for each age group manually (`prop.table` then using odds=p/(1-p)).  If you want to test the association statistically you should look into multinomial or ordinal regression.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you. I'll edit to focus on the first question only.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva, yes, thank you. However, with the real data, I'm dealing with crosstabs only.